# Grafana Tempo doesn't show traces after sometime

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, open-telemetry, grafana-tempo

hi i have setup grafana tempo with opentelemetry in my EKS cluster. at initial time tempo show traces but after 1 hr none trace show on grafana it show me `404 Not Found`

[image: Error screenshot]

here is my tempo configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  overrides.yaml: |
    overrides:

      ingestion_rate_limit_bytes: 400000
      max_bytes_per_trace: 0
      max_search_bytes_per_trace: 100000000
  tempo.yaml: |
    auth_enabled: false
    compactor:
        compaction:
            compacted_block_retention: 24h
            compaction_window: 1h
            block_retention: 1h

    distributor:
        receivers:
            jaeger:
                protocols:
                    thrift_compact:
                        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:6831
            otlp:
                protocols:
                    grpc:
                        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:55680
    ingester:
      lifecycler:
        ring:
          replication_factor: 1

      trace_idle_period: 1s
      max_block_duration: 10m
    server:
        http_listen_port: 3200
    storage:
        trace:
            backend: local
            block:
              bloom_filter_false_positive: .05
            blocklist_poll: 30s
            local:
                path: /tmp/tempo/traces
            wal:
                path: /var/tempo/wal
            pool:
              max_workers: 1000
              queue_depth: 200000


    overrides:
      ingestion_rate_limit_bytes: 400000
      max_bytes_per_trace: 0
      max_search_bytes_per_trace: 100000000

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tempo
  namespace: monitoring
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: tempo
  name: tempo
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tempo-prom-metrics
    port: 3200
    targetPort: 3200
  - name: tempo-otlp
    port: 55680
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 55680
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3200
  - name: receiver
    port: 6831
    protocol: UDP
    targetPort: 6831
  selector:
    app: tempo
    name: tempo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: tempo
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 10
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tempo
      name: tempo

  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        config_hash: 7f4b5fad0e6364b6a2a5ea380281cb0e
      labels:
        app: tempo
        name: tempo
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -config.file=/conf/tempo.yaml
        - -mem-ballast-size-mbs=1024
        env:
        - name: JAEGER_AGENT_PORT
          value: ""
        image: grafana/tempo:main-e6394c3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: tempo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3200
          name: prom-metrics
        - containerPort: 55680
          name: otlp
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /conf
          name: tempo-conf
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: tempo
        name: tempo-conf
```

OTEL configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: collector-config
  namespace: prod-aro-eks-clone
  labels:
    app: opentelemetry
    component: otel-collector-conf
data:
  collector.yaml: |
    receivers:
      # Make sure to add the otlp receiver.
      # This will open up the receiver on port 4317


      otlp:
        protocols:
         grpc:
           endpoint: "0.0.0.0:5555"
         http:


      hostmetrics:
        collection_interval: 20s
        scrapers:
          cpu:
            metrics:
             system.cpu.utilization:
               enabled: true
          load:
          memory:
            metrics:
              system.memory.utilization:
                enabled: true
          disk:
          filesystem:
            metrics:
              system.filesystem.utilization:
                enabled: true
          network:
          paging:
            metrics:
              system.paging.utilization:
                enabled: true
          processes:
          process:


      k8s_cluster:
        collection_interval: 10s
        node_conditions_to_report: [Ready, MemoryPressure,DiskPressure,NetworkUnavailable]
        allocatable_types_to_report: [cpu, memory,storage]


      k8s_events:
        auth_type : serviceAccount

      receiver_creator:
         watch_observers: [k8s_observer]
         receivers:
            kubeletstats:
              rule: type == "k8s.node"
              config:
                collection_interval: 10s
                auth_type: serviceAccount
                endpoint: "`endpoint`:`kubelet_endpoint_port`"
                insecure_skip_verify: true
                extra_metadata_labels:
                  - container.id
                  - k8s.volume.type
                metric_groups:
                  - node
                  - pod
                  - volume
                  - container







      prometheus:
        config:
          scrape_configs:

            - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
              scrape_interval: 5s
              scrape_timeout: 1s
              static_configs:
                - targets: ['kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:8080']
            - job_name: k8s
              kubernetes_sd_configs:
              - role: pod
              relabel_configs:
              - source_labels: ['__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape']
                regex: "true"
                action: keep
              metric_relabel_configs:
              - source_labels: [__name__]
                regex: "(request_duration_seconds.*|response_duration_seconds.*)"
                action: keep
    processors:
      memory_limiter:
        check_interval: 1s
        limit_mib: 2000
        spike_limit_mib: 500
      batch:
        timeout: 10s
        send_batch_size: 10000
      spanmetrics:
        metrics_exporter: prometheus
        latency_histogram_buckets: [100ms, 250ms,500ms,1s,2s,4s,6s,8s,10s,20s,30s]
        dimensions:
          - name: http.method
          - name: http.status_code
          - name: db.operation
          - name: db.statement
          - name: exception.message
          - name: exception.type
          - name: messaging.message.id
          - name: messaging.message.payload_size_bytes
        dimensions_cache_size: 10000
        aggregation_temporality: "AGGREGATION_TEMPORALITY_CUMULATIVE"
      servicegraph:
        metrics_exporter: prometheus
      transform:
         metric_statements:
           - context: metric
             statements:
               - set(description, "Measures the duration of inbound HTTP requests") where name == "http.server.duration"
      cumulativetodelta:
        include:
          metrics:
           - system.network.io
           - system.disk.operations
           - system.network.dropped
           - system.network.packets
           - process.cpu.time
          match_type: strict
      resource:
        attributes:
          - key: host.id
            from_attribute: host.name
            action: upsert
      resourcedetection:


        detectors: [env, system]


      k8sattributes:
        auth_type: serviceAccount
        passthrough: false
        filter:
          node_from_env_var: K8S_NODE_NAME
        extract:
          metadata:
            - k8s.pod.name
            - k8s.pod.uid
            - k8s.deployment.name
            - k8s.namespace.name
            - k8s.node.name
            - k8s.pod.start_time


      metricstransform:
        transforms:
           include: .+
           match_type: regexp
           action: update
           operations:
             - action: add_label
               new_label: kubernetes.cluster.id
               new_value: CLUSTER_ID_TO_REPLACE
             - action: add_label
               new_label: kubernetes.name
               new_value: prod-aro

    extensions:
      health_check: {}

    exporters:



      otlp:
        endpoint: "http://tempo.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:55680"
        tls:
          insecure: true



      prometheus:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:6666"



      logging:
        loglevel: info


      loki:
         endpoint: http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/push
         labels:
           resource:
             container.name: "container_name"
             k8s.cluster.name: "k8s_cluster_name"
             k8s.event.reason: "k8s_event_reason"
             k8s.object.kind: "k8s_object_kind"
             k8s.object.name: "k8s_object_name"
             k8s.object.uid: "k8s_object_uid"
             k8s.object.fieldpath: "k8s_object_fieldpath"
             k8s.object.api_version: "k8s_object_api_version"
           attributes:
             k8s.event.reason: "k8s_event_reason"
             k8s.event.action: "k8s_event_action"
             k8s.event.start_time: "k8s_event_start_time"
             k8s.event.name: "k8s_event_name"
             k8s.event.uid: "k8s_event_uid"
             k8s.namespace.name: "k8s_namespace_name"
             k8s.event.count: "k8s_event_count"
           record:
             traceID: "traceid"
    service:
      extensions: [health_check]
      pipelines:

          logs:
            receivers: [k8s_events]
            processors: [memory_limiter,k8sattributes,batch]
            exporters: [loki,logging]
          traces:
            receivers: [otlp]
            processors: [spanmetrics,servicegraph,batch]
            exporters: [otlp]
          metrics:
            receivers: [otlp,prometheus]
            processors: [memory_limiter,metricstransform,k8sattributes,resourcedetection,batch]
            exporters: [logging,prometheus,otlp]
      telemetry:
        logs:
          level: info
          initial_fields:
            service: my-prom-instance
```

and i want to highlight one point here as well after restart of OTEL pod tempo again show the traces on grafana. seems collector stop fetching the traces after sometime. so again after restart the OTEL service it again start to fetch traces.

tempo should show traces for the long time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `block_retention` configuration.

In your tempo.yaml configuration, you currently have `block_retention: 1h` configured, which is why you aren't able to query traces older than 1 hour.

---

From the [Grafana Tempo documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/tempo/latest/configuration/#compactor),

> Optional. Duration to keep blocks.  Default is 14 days (336h).

Comment: Hi Brad i tried with your solution and now block_retention is 336h but still my traces is not showing


failed to get trace with id: 68085ddc7de68883f8159d16a297de86 Status: 404 Not Found Body: trace not found
this is my recent trace but still showing the same. as i said it work well for initial 30 40 min.

Comment: is there any way to know that opentelemetry is fetching tracing or not. because after restart of opentelemetry we again get the traces